# Store GIF from URL as object variable

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

https://media2.giphy.com/media/JpYdtQifMv3SAsnf8j/giphy.gif?cid=f25c51ea3ef14717fe448ab031d8a047c77d1438043fcca6&rid=giphy.gif

I want to extract the image from the URL above as an object variable, or BLOB, or whatever would be best.

How do I do this ?

I tried Get with axios and it did not work.

The end goal is to upload the object to an S3 folder later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use fetch here. [Some examples list how to load images via the `blob` body api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request#Examples)

```
async function loadData(url) {
  const resp = await fetch(url)
  const data = await resp.blob()
  const imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data);
  return imgUrl
}
```

where you can set an `image.src` to be this url

Comment: this was a thing of beauty